# ClassCastException when iterating over HashSet

Tags: java, set, hashset, classcastexception

I have a `HashSet<String>` that's filled with strings called `shingles` (if you take the string "Fizzbuzz" and break it into shingles, you'd get "Fi", "iz", "zz", "zb", "bu", "uz", "zz". Not important, but that's what a shingle is in this context).

I'm trying to return a string of the HashSet's contents via the method below:

```
public String getShinglesAsString() {
    String shingles = "";
    for (String shingle : this.shingles) {
        shingles += shingle + " ";
    }

    return shingles;
}
```

The `for (String shingle : this.shingles)` is throwing a ClassCastException. The specific message is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence`.

I've also tried using an Iterator object, and I get the same issue. This is my code to generate the shingles from a string fed to the constructor:

```
// Will generate a new set of shingles based on sentence
public void generateShingles() {
    shingles = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i=0; i<getSentence().length()-1; i++) {
        getShingles().add(getSentence().charAt(i) + getSentence().charAt(i+1));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the [minmal, complete, verifiable example:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
public class SentenceWithShingles {
private String sentence;
private Set<String> shingles;

// Constructor
public SentenceWithShingles(String sentence) {
    this.sentence = sentence;
    generateShingles();
}

// Will generate a new set of shingles based on sentence
public void generateShingles() {
    shingles = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i=0; i<getSentence().length()-1; i++) {
        getShingles().add(getSentence().charAt(i) + getSentence().charAt(i+1));
    }
}

public void setSentence(String sentence) {
    this.sentence = sentence;
}

public Set getShingles() {
    return shingles;
}

public String getShinglesAsString() {
    String shingles = "";
    for (String shingle : this.shingles) {
        shingles += shingle + " ";
    }

    return shingles;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `this.shingles`, is it defined as an collection of `Objects`?

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the return type of getShingles?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have the wrong line of code. Maybe the line numbers are off.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify:
this.shingles is defined as a `private Set<String>`.
the return type of getShingles is `Set`.
tbodt: That's the line that NetBeans is giving me an error on, double checked, so I don't think I have the wrong line. 
Oliver, let me get started on that.

Comment: What it means is that you've got an Integer object in `this.shingles`.  The fact that it may be defined as `Set<String>` does not limit it to only containing String objects.

Comment: (Doubt me?  Do `for (Object test : this.shingles) { System.out.println("The class is " + test.getClass().toString()); }`.)

Comment: You're correct! Somehow all of my shingles have been converted to numbers.

Comment: (I think some folks owe Mike Nakis an apology.  He was right.)

Comment: I'm not sure who Mike is, but I do owe tbodt an apology. Sorry, tbodt, you were correct. Thanks again for your help, everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
getShingles().add(getSentence().charAt(i) + getSentence().charAt(i+1));
```

That line adds the two characters together. Not concatenating them.

```
getShingles().add(getSentence().charAt(i) + "" + getSentence().charAt(i+1));
```

Will force the right semantics.